# Detect 3.5mm jack button press when app is in foreground

Tags: win-universal-app

I have an audio background task with the following:

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls.ButtonPressed += (sender, e) =>
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine("Button pressed: " + e.Button.ToString());
};
```

This works when I hold the button and release after a second.

I want to use this in foreground without a background task. Is it possible to do this without using `BackgroundMediaPlayer`? I have tried using `MediaElement`, but I couldn't find a `ButtonPressed` event or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by using [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187272.aspx) and SystemMediaTransportControls class.The [SystemMediaTransportControls class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn278677) contains the `ButtonPressed` event.The document [System Media Transport Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls) guides to how to do this. And there is an [offical sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls) that already meet your requirements. You can test the sample directly. Here is parts of the sample's code.

Xaml Code

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MyMediaElement" Margin="0,0,10,0" AudioCategory="Media" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Code behind

```
private SystemMediaTransportControls systemMediaControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();    
systemMediaControls.IsEnabled = true;
systemMediaControls.ButtonPressed += systemMediaControls_ButtonPressed;
private async void systemMediaControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            switch (args.Button)
            {
                case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Button pressed: ");
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

> Yes, it's not called when I press the button which is plugged into the headset port.

If you want to trigger an event when the headset plugged in, please use this API [AudioRoutingManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.media.devices.audioroutingmanager.aspx). And code example as follows:

```
 private void Detectheadset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     AudioRoutingManager manager = AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault();
     manager.AudioEndpointChanged += Manager_AudioEndpointChanged;        
 }

 private void Manager_AudioEndpointChanged(AudioRoutingManager sender, object args)
 { 
 }
```

Pay attention to add relative capabilities and add reference for `Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP`. Since this is a mobile extension namespace, run it on the phone.

Comment: I added `systemMediaControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;` and tried enabling every button, but `systemMediaControls_ButtonPressed` is not called when I press the button. I have one similar to these: [image](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61TnbxASYfL._SL1010_.jpg). No error either.

Comment: @Nfear have you used the official sample   for testing? My code is not the full here.

Comment: Yes, it's not called when I press the button which is plugged into the headset port. It is called when I press pause on the volume control menu.

Comment: @Nfear Sorry as your code uploaded is the function of the headset's control menu. So I give the answer for the control menu. I'll update the answer please see the new answer and trying.